# What does the phonemes parameter do in metaphone()?

Tags: php

From the examples in the documentation, a larger phonemes length parameter somehow makes the result less accurate (more fuzzy) but how does the phonemes length actually change the algorithm?

In the PHP documentation examples:

```
metaphone('programming');    //PRKRMNK
metaphone('programmer');     //PRKRMR
metaphone('programming', 5); //PRKRM
metaphone('programmer', 5);  //PRKRM
```

How would I know when to use a positive value for phonemes for metaphone?